# Power minimization in a battery powered NFC Reader?

Tags: embedded, low-power, battery-operated, rfid, nfc

I have been trying to design a **Battery powered NFC Reader** using **Quectel SC60 module** with **SAM interface**.

So , the problem is that in the reference design, **LDO is always connected to VBAT** thus draining my battery continuously(even in sleep mode).
And, I can't disable the LDO as that will switch off the Tranceiver/Reader IC as well thus making the device inefficient.I guess the Reader has to be always on to detect any incoming tags,right?

So **what should I do** in such case to **improve my battery performance and reduce drainage** ?

Pardon my limited knowledge of Readers,if I am wrong above.

**Thanks in advance for the support !**

The relevant links are as follows :

[NFC Reference design](http://183.82.99.162:8000/Quectel/LTE%20Module/SC60/02%20Hardware/Quectel_SC60_NFC_Reference_Design_Rev.A_20180420.pdf)

[Datasheets and other details of SC60](https://www.quectel.com/ProductDownload/SC60.zip)

Comment: Where's the datasheet for the LDO?   There are LDO's with very low quiescent currents... whats the Q current on yours?   I looked at the ref design, that LDO has a resistor-divider to set it's program voltage - That'll waste uber current.  Use an LDO with a built-in reference (i.e. a fixed output voltage instead of adjustable)

Comment: @KyleB ! Thanks for the suggestion. I will definitely try to follow it. BTW, since the design is still in it's very initial stage, I have not yet chosen the LDO. When I looked at the reference design, this question came to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

The NFC chip is powered from Vbat and well from the LDO's 1.85V. Can not give advice on efficiency without knowing the current from the LDO in standby. It is probably negligible, as your NFC standby polling power is presumably from the Vbat supply.

If you want to save on power and send the NFC reader into sleep add an accelerometer to detect motion and wake up the reader.

Comment: Thanks @barbazoo for the suggestion. I will definitely try to follow it.